# control tree in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to build tree structure like below,I have searched a lot of times,but I couldn't get example in codeigniter.If any one can help me it'll very useful for me.

When I click on child node 2 I need to load some data from database.

**I need like this tree structure:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, Where is "Below" tree structure ?

Comment: thanks for reminding on my mistake, I have edited the question.

Comment: Which one is child node 2?

Comment: ohh really sorry it is linear algebra,I need to load separate content for this

Answer (score 1):

You should give enough information about the type of data that you are going to fetch from the database for your tree. Anyways you can use some css tree structure for your purpose.

Follow this link to get the plugin ... [TheCssNinja](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu).

Try iterating the data you have obtained from the database using php to generate HTML tags like as specified in the doc of plugin I mentioned above <OL> and <LI>.

If you want to go for jquery tree, then you can go with [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/).